# Xamarin Forms Master Detail Keep Master on the left

Tags: c#, xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I am trying to keep the Master page (menu) to the left of My MasterDetailPage at all times, I do not want the navigation to take the user away from the MasterDetailPage and make the user press a back button to get back.

I am looking a traditional burger bar menu to the left that simply changes the Detail page and keeps the master in place.

What I have now:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static NavigationPage NavPage { get; private set; }
    private static RootPage RootPage;
    public static bool MenuIsPresented
    {
        get
        {
            return RootPage.IsPresented;
        }
        set
        {
            RootPage.IsPresented = value;
        }
    }
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MenuPage menuPage = new MenuPage();
        NavPage = new NavigationPage(new FirstPage());
        RootPage = new RootPage();
        RootPage.Master = menuPage;
        RootPage.Detail = NavPage;
        MainPage = RootPage;

    }
...
}
```

And my ViewModel Command

```
async void GoSecondPageAsync(object obj)
    {
        await App.NavPage.PushAsync(new SecondPage());
        App.MenuIsPresented = false;
    }
```

But this just creates a new page on top of the stack with a back button back to the MasterDetailPage, while all I want is to stay within the MasterDetailPage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push the new page and just remove the first one from the `NavigationStack` For example:

```
async void GoSecondPageAsync(object obj)
{
    await App.NavPage.PushAsync(new SecondPage());
    var removePage = App.NavPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[0];
    App.NavPage.Navigation.RemovePage(removePage);
    App.MenuIsPresented = false;
}
```

Although, if you just always want to replace the page do you really even need the NavigationPage and can't you just set the `RootPage.Detail=new SecondPage();`

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your reply! I have actually changed the scope of my Root page from private to public and added the detail as a new instance of the page to navigate too. But I was just fearing it was inefficient way to navigate and was wondering if there was a tried and tested way. So far though, the performance seems fine.

Comment: Yeah removing from the stack isn't that performance heavy, but you're probably better off just setting a new Detail Page

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update the Detail property to point to the new page. Like this:

```
async void GoSecondPageAsync(object obj)
    {
        RootPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new SecondPage());
        App.MenuIsPresented = false;
    }
```