# Xamarin.Forms Navigation Stack iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, navigation, back-stack

currently I'm developing my first *Xamarin.Forms* app. In general everything is working fine, but there is a huge problem with navigating through the stack. With Android it is working like expected, I'm using *PushAsync* and *PopAsync*, iOS works just once. I'm calling a *ContentPage* with *PushAsync* and it is displayed, when going back with *PopAsync* everything is fine, if I choose another *ContentPage* it is working also, but if I'm calling the same *ContentPage* which I *Popped* before iOS is just showing a blank screen. The debugged stack looks okay the Page is on top of it.

I implemented something like a small *lifecycle* for all my Pages which initializes Views, sets GestureRecognizers and wraps the *Content* in some layout with BottomBar etc. This seems to work fine when debugging.

Basically I'm an Android developer and have not that much experience with iOS, is there anything obvious what could trigger such a behavior ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you calling multiple PopAsync from the same page?

Comment: Yes sometimes this could happen, I'm using ScnViewGestures for handling TouchDown and TouchUp Events, these are triggerd multiple times in certain circumstances. But after all the requested amount of PopAsync calls is correct

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to remove multiple pages at a time in quick succession, which I'd suggest removing a page from the NavigationStack and then popping the top page off with PopAsync instead

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correct, is it possible to give me a simple practical example ?

Comment: Some code would be helpful to see when/how you are actually navigating, but this answer might give you a better idea of what I mean by removing the page from the NavigationStack  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600039/xamarin-forms-master-detail-keep-master-on-the-left/45600411#45600411 and then after you'd call PopAsync to remove the top page that is If you are navigating away from multiple pages at the same time

Comment: Thats was exactly the problem, thank you very much Nick it worked with removing and PopAsync after.